# Поменять поле для ключа в модели. Django

Tags: python, python-3.x, django

Может кто сталкивался и находил решение без дампа и удаления таблиц. Не могу себе позволить выключить базу данных на проде.

Есть модель:

```py
class Invoice(models.Model):
    ppm_client = models.ForeignKey(AvardeClient, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    invoice_id = models.BigIntegerField(primary_key=True, default=None)
    invoice_j = models.JSONField(default = dict)
    isArchive = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    isPogoSent = models.BooleanField(default=False)
```

Хочу удалить `primary_key=True` для поля `invoice_id` и сделать миграцию с автоматическим добавлением поля `id` и внесенеим в каждую запись автоинкремент по данному полю.

Есть ли решение, без удаления записей\таблиц из базы?

Версия `django`: Django 3.2.5

Answer (score 1):

удалите primary_key у поле invoice_id
добавьте поле id
создайте миграцию

Потом добавьте запуск функции в миграции после создание айди поле, например:

```
from django.db import migrations, models
from django.db.models import F


def change_id(apps, schema_editor):
    Invoice = apps.get_model('APP_NAME', 'Invoice')
    Invoice.objects.update(id=F('invoice_id'))


class Migration(migrations.Migration):

    dependencies = [
        # нужные зависимости, которые указал джанго при создание файл миграции
    ]

    operations = [
        # Добавление нового поле id
        migrations.RunPython(
            change_id,
            reverse_code=migrations.RunPython.noop,
        ),
       # удаление праймери кей у поле invoice_id

    ]
```

вроде так можно решить)